# React Context API & HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been reading up on the new context API and have a question regarding using it alongside HOC to inject props instead of directly wrapping every child that needs access to some state with a Consumer.

Isn't the above achievable *without* context? Isn't it possible to just house some state in a HOC and inject that into wrapped components that need access?

Comment: I understand the question. But I want to mention that if you want to inject props instead of wrapping the components or reduce the number of consumers, you could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-consumer-hoc (which allows wrapping a component on export and the context is passed as a prop, it also increases modularity and testability) or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-combine-contexts (which allows using multiple contexts with a single Consumer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible but each wrapped component will have it's own data passed from HOC. While using context, this data is shared between components.

So changing data in a context will make all `Consumers` re-render, while HOC will work only for the wrapped component.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation explains the use case where a lot of components need to access the **common theme**, and hence can be wrapped with an HOC. without the `context`, you can make use of HOCs state to store the variable and pass on to the components wrapped with HOC but all of these components will have a different instance of the state and won't react to the theme change together.

`Context` makes it possible to store the data centrally and all listeners/consumers will react to the change together.

Comment: Do you have to construct the Provider as a HOC in order to update state everywhere that the Provider is used in the App?

Comment: @ardev, generally you would have only one Provider and many consumers, so the provider shouldn't be an HOC, however in cases where you need to have multiple provider which should be an extremely rare case, you need to create multiple consumer HOCs or an HOC that takes each provider as an argument